# Character detection working in Chrome; not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I need to stop users from entering a colon or pipe on our web script, and I've used this piece of code:

```
}
function colonFilter(evt)
{
  var e = event || evt; 
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if (charCode == 58 || charCode == 124)
  return false;

  return true;

}
```

It works fine in Chrome, however, when I access the site in Firefox it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I wonder what exactly "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: It blocks the input when I'm using chrome, but Firefox still lets me input a colon or pipe.

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the browser console? Have you checked to see what `charCode` actually is in Firefox? (Use `console.log(charCode)` for that.)

Comment: Oh, also, how is this function being called?

Comment: <input name="description" type="text" onkeypress="return colonFilter();" size="60" maxlength="255" value="">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the event object to the function. Chrome mimics Internet Explorer and maintains a global "event"; Firefox does not.

```
<input name="description" type="text" onkeypress="return colonFilter(event);" size="60" maxlength="255" value="">
```

That'll work in all browsers.